Shimano Alifine 8 IGH yellow dots will NOT line up
With shifter in 4th gear, per instructions, the upper yellow dot is about 3/16" ahead (clockwise) of the lower yellow dot. Whether I adjust the barrel connector (at the shifter) to one extreme or to the other, making sure to shift up to 8th then down to 1st then back to 4th before checking again, the yellow dots remain in exactly the same relation to each other.
My question: What does this mean? What do I need to do?
Thank you.

Do the gears work properly? Are there other symptoms?

I went back out to my workshop this morning and the barrel adjuster works and a few turns put the yellow dots in perfect alignment. Go figure.  But thank you for replying.

That sounds like something travels slowly. I'd have a look at the shifter cable, see if it moves freely (i suspect it doesn't). Add some lube or oil, if it doesn't, or replace the shifter cable if it's rusty or frayed.
